# Where did Wm. Herschel plan to put their head? Peer over the edge of the famous 40-foot telescope or try to get less off-axis; closer to the center?

Tags: astronomy, optics, telescope

From [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:William_Herschel_Museum_-_40-foot_telescope_model_1.jpg):

[image: Herschel 40 foot telescope model] [image: Herschel 40 foot telescope model]

click for larger

Herschel's [40 foot telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40-foot_telescope) had a diameter of 48 inches (122 cm) and was f/10. It was not a good mirror (cast in metal) and apparently not used that much.

But my question is about where the eyepiece was planned to be held during normal use (which may not have happened). The Wikipedia article says only:

> The telescope was located on the grounds of Observatory House, Herschel's house in Slough, between 1789 and 1840. The first observation with the telescope was on 19 February 1787, when Herschel pointed the then-incomplete telescope towards the Orion nebula, which he observed by crawling into the telescope and using a hand-held eyepiece: "The apparatus for the 40-foot telescope was by this time so far completed that I could put the mirror into the tube and direct it to a celestial object; but having no eye-glass fixed, not being acquainted with the focal length which was to be tried, I went into the tube, and laying down near the mouth of it I held the eye-glass in my hand, and soon found the place of the focus. The object I viewed was the nebula in the belt of Orion, and I found the figure of the mirror, though far from perfect, better than I had expected. It showed four small stars in the nebula and many more. The nebula was extremely bright."

The above quote describes some tests of the mirror when the telescope was not yet complete, I'm asking about the plan for the completed configuration.

**Question:** Where did [William Herschel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Herschel) plan to put their head when looking through the famous 40-foot telescope? Was the plan to peer over the edge of the tube or try to get less off-axis; closer to the center and basically partially block the aperture with the upper body? Or was there going to be a diagonal mirror like a [Newtonian telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_telescope)?

Comment: The origin of this question is in the writing of [this answer to *DIY telescope to observe nebulae*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43850/7982)

Comment: I believe Richard Holmes'  "The Age of Wonder" has a long chapter on Herschel's work.  It's a good read.

Comment: The observer will look as is shown in your right hand side picture: over the edge of the tube. The eyepiece of a Newtonian does not have to be at the center of the tube.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko In the case of spherical or parabolic mirrors (i.e. axisymmetric), there will be some distortion moving even half-way between the center and edge. I'll see if I can calculate it tomorrow, but I think it would be quite large. Since the mirror was cast metal rather than polished glass, I wonder if the shape was corrected for off-axis distortion somehow? Or for best resolution did Herschel or other observers actually sometimes move close to the center?

Comment: @uhoh   Who is "Sir Herschel"?  The 40 foot telescope was built by William Herschel and it was his son John who was knighted.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I'll fix that, thanks! William is an FRS, and in a mixture of ignorance and haste it seems that I've knighted him or perhaps "merged him" with John. I see now that (by total coincidence) someone else has knighted Willam also? From Wikipedia's [John Herschel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Herschel) "Sir John Frederick William Herschel, 1st Baronet KH FRS, 7 (March 1792 – 11 May 1871)... originated the use of the Julian day system in astronomy. He named seven moons of Saturn and four moons of Uranus – the seventh planet, *discovered by his father Sir William Herschel*."

Comment: @uhoh: 1. At that time nobody knew how to make a parabolic mirror (and still does not know, except by using computers). 2. Concerning spherical mirrors, a sphere does not have a distinguished axis. So small displacement of the observer with respect to the axis of the tube is irrelevant.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko spheres have centers, and parallel rays from any given object reflected from a spherical mirror t in a plane containing the center will all pass through a single axis. We use [paraxial ray approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation) with spherical optics all the time, nobody says "Hey we gotta stop this and throw out all of our results, somebody in Stack Exchange just discovered that spheres don't have axes!" It makes sense to use the word axis the way that I did.

Comment: @uhoh, yes, but the center of the sphere does not have to be on the axis of the tube. I've seen schemes of Newtonians where the center of the sphere is on the edge of the tube, and I suppose that this particular one is of this type.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko yes that is very true! **update:** rats! I was just going to ask who made the first parabolic mirror but it seems that's been answered (by you) already :-) [Hadley made a parabolic mirror in 1721, for a Newtonian telescope btw.](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/2059/3869) fyi I've just asked [How was the first parabolic telescope mirror made, and how was it used/what problem did it solve?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/13203/3869)

Comment: "It was not a good mirror (cast in metal) and apparently not used that much." It was a perfectly good mirror, since after it was cast it was polished to its final figure, just like most glass mirrors are. The lack of use was more due to the unwieldy nature of the mount.